# SVG fonts in Inkscape

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I know how to turn a path into a SVG font character in Inkscape. There are tons of tutorials online showing how to do it. However, I do not know how to edit a SVG font in Inkscape. What if I do not want to start from scratch? What if I want to take an existing character in a font file, and modify it?

Is that possible? If not, is it possible in, for instance, Illustrator? Or some other software?

Comment: I don't understand what are you exactly meaning. If you need to *modify an existing font*, Inkscape is only an intermediate way to edit the character, and you need something like [Fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io/) to update the font, see also [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21646/is-it-possible-to-add-new-characters-to-a-font). If you need to *modify an existing character* and use it in a drawing, you can simply type the character and convert it to a path.

Comment: The latter is what I want. However, it becomes kind of impractical if I am modifying characters from several Wingdings-like fonts. I am just looking for an easier approach than installing tons of fonts.

Comment: Mmm. Could be helpful a font manager like NexusFont or similar? With a font manager you can use the fonts without installing permanently them.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Okay, well, how do I do that? I cannot find any tutorials online on how to use NexusFont with Inkscape...

Comment: NexusFont is an example for Windows. Font managers can allow the applications (and Inkscape too) to use the needed font on the fly, without installing the font itself. There is no specific integration with Inkscape: a font manager works at operating system level.